# How to generate an image in python pixel by pixel?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm having a go at writing an image generator for a graphical format that I created that uses 0 as a delimiter:

Here is an example.
An extract from a sample file:

```
202000200030FFFF000F0122202071960104203023302024.....
```

Breaking this down

```
2 0 Version is 2 
200 0   Image Width is 200 pixels 
200 0   Image Height is 200 pixels 
3 0 There are 3 colours 
FFFF00 0    The first colour is FFFF00  
F01222 0    The second colour is F01222 
207196 0    The third colour is 207196 
104703023302024 ... This is the image
```

Then breaking the image bit 204703023302044 down:

```
2 0 Select Colour One
42 0    Draw 42 pixels
3 0 Select Colour Three
233 0   Draw 233 pixels
2 0 Select Colour Two
24 0    Draw 24 pixels
```

How would I generate an image pixel by pixel using this format? I'd use PIL but am open to suggestions. If I was to use PIL then how would I do this?

Comment: Using `0` as delimiter is not good choice, because data itself contains `0`. Use other character not included in `[0-9][A-Fa-f]`(hexadecimal digits).

Comment: If I had to use 0 as a delimiter how would I go about it.

Comment: To use `0` as a delimiter you would have to make sure one could never occur in a place where its meaning was ambiguous -- so it couldn't be mistaken for something else, like the pixel data itself. It's also unclear whether you mean binary `0` or the ASCII character `'0'` in your examples.

Comment: Inventing a new image format is as ungrateful as inventing a new cipher - failure dooms and you are unlikely to match openly specified (and extendable) ones like PNG, which supports palette based pictures and better compression than run length encoding. Its unclear, how image size specifications are handled: if 0x200 pixels are intended, how would you recognize your delimiter? PILs focus is to handle standard formats. It may have a hook for export of new formats (I'm unsure), but writing a binary file is the same in python as everywhere: open it in binary mode and write it byte by byte.

Comment: @guidot it's really for a personal research project more than anything else- definitely not for actual use.

Comment: @akkatracker You may want to look a [struct module](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/struct.html) for functions to convert your numbers and values to a byte string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would change your delimiter since you can not know if a 0 is a delimiter or a part of a value, also you should use a fixed number of digits for colour values, possibly specified as part of the header, after that it is just a matter of reading the header then reading the data into an array and calling PIL.Image.fromarray to create your image and taking it from there.

Comment: If I had to use 0 as a delimiter how would I go about it.

Comment: @akkatracker - Do you? If so, why?

Comment: Well just for an obvious example `2 0` could mean either `Select Colour Two` or `Draw 2 pixels`. How would you decide which one?

Comment: @root just out of pure curiosity :P

Comment: @Brian it would depend on where it was placed. If it was after a colour selection then it would mean draw 2 pixels

If it was after a draw 'x' pixels it would mean select colour 2

Comment: My problem with 0 as a separator is if the file if an entry reads ff0000000000000000 is it a red pixel followed by 2 black, with a zero after each entry of ff or 00 i.e. ff0 000, 000 then 000, 000, 000 or is it a red pixel ff0 00 00 followed by black 00 00 00 * 3 - most confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is called run-length encoding, or RLE. It was used as a compression scheme in the BMP format. You can find a Python implementation of some simple BMP file storage (including RLE) at http://www.ptmcg.com/geo/python/bmp.py.txt.

But the choice of '0' for delimiter is baffling. In your posted example, how do you know that the width is 200 pixels? It could be 20 pixels with a delimiter of 0, or 2 pixels with a delimiter of 0. Or 20002 with a delimiter of 0. If you must use 0 as a delimiter, then use another character for 0, maybe 'z' or '_'. Pick a delimiter that does not exist in the data, or structure the data so that there is no confusion with a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll look at restructuring

Answer (score 1):

I gave this some more thought, and your '0' delimiter *can* work, using a regex with a non-consuming lookahead. Essentially, your '0' delimiter is the rightmost '0' before a non-zero.

Define a regex for the '0' delimiter (a '0' that is followed by something that is not a '0' or the end of the string)

```
>>> import re
>>> last_zero_delim = re.compile(r"0(?=[^0]|$)")
```

Use re.split with this pattern to break up the input string

```
>>> z = '202000200030FFFF000F01222020719601042030233020240'
>>> re.split(last_zero_delim,z)
['2', '200', '200', '3', 'FFFF00', 'F', '1222', '2', '7196', '1', '42', '3', '233', '2', '24', '']
```

Now you can work through this list to process the pixel-counts and color palette indexes.

Comment: Rats, this fails on 'F01222', as well as any number containing a '0', as in '103 pixels of color 2' becomes the ambiguous mess '103020' - you just need a different delimiter, I'm afraid.